# Помогите составить II нормальную форму БД?

Tags: база-данных

Я составил I нормальную форму для БД. Раскидав поля по разным таблицам, я получил другую структуру, но мне кажется, что это уже III нормальная форма. А мне для наглядности отчёта хотелось бы показать еще вторую. Или если я не прав и это II форма, как получить III?
Извините, что кидаю ссылки: не хватает репутации, чтобы залить сюда.

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

Comment: IMHO это уже III нормальная форма.



--

Не знаю, как насчет жанра, а вот **несколько авторов** у книги это не редкость.

Так что, еще одну табличку *код-книги/код-автора* надо бы добавить.

--

Вы наверняка читали про [нормальные формы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0).  

Так вот, если в эту табличку перенести некоторые  атрибуты из таблиц *Книги* и *Автор*, то получите схему во второй форме.

Comment: первая таблица не в 1-й НФ. т.к. присутствуют ключи и значения, описывающие одну и ту же сущность, например, код издательства и издательство. В этой таблице не должно быть кодов, только значения.

Comment: вторая форма получится, например, после декомпозиции на две сущности книга и заказ. и код должен появиться только у книги, на который будет ссылка в заказе. это будет не третья форма из-за транзитивных зависимостей.  
**upd** подумалось, что и тут код не нужен. книгу однозначно идентифицирует название, автор, год (по хорошему использовать ISBN, но в друг там самиздат какой-то), поэтому ссылка на книгу в заказе будет составной - на список ключевых полей.

Comment: ну а у вас уже третья нф. у заказа, правда, кода не должно быть. номер может быть, но это не код. вот если дальше у вас появятся сущность в которых будут ссылки на заказ, то да, в коде будет смысл. в таком виде ключом является номер+дата.

Comment: Согласен с уваж. @avp: без "многое ко многому" Вам не обойтись. Особенно, если торговать, например, научно-популярными журналами; там соавторство - частое явление. А так, получилась у Вас вполне пристойная НФ, по крайней мере, не ниже третьей. Мне понравилось.

Comment: тут на самом деле вопрос в том, какая задача решается. в качестве обучения написать структуру баз в разных НФ или создать структуру, с которой удобно работать. В частности суррогатные ключи для корректной 3-й НФ не нужны, но в реальной жизни без них никуда...

Answer (score 1):

Уточнение, **нормальная форма** это термин, который относится к отношению (таблице), но не ко всей БД.

Теперь по поводу 2НФ в отношении данных таблиц. Мы знаем из определения, что отношение, которое находится в 1НФ и у которой все не ключевые атрибуты зависят целиком (т.е. в составе ключа нет под-ключей) от ключа (потенциальных ключей), находится во 2НФ.

Ввиду вышесказанного все отношения у которых имеется ключ, состоящий лишь из одного атрибута находятся во 2НФ, в данном случае это: *Код, Автор, Издательство, Жанр,* ну и скорее всего *Оператор* и *Покупатель* (у них на схеме не указаны ключи в самих таблицах просто).

Остаётся отношение *Заказ*. У него имеется составной ключ (если судить по схеме): *Код книги, Код оператора, Код клиента* и атрибут *Код заказа*, который скорее всего и является первичным ключом (если посмотреть на список атрибутов в первой таблице). Если это так и у отношения *Заказ* основой ключ это *Код заказа*, то она также находится во 2НФ. Если же ключ всё-таки составной, то и в данном случае отношение отношение будет находится во 2НФ, так как ни *Код книги*, ни *Код оператора*, ни *Код клиента* поодиночке и в комбинации друг с другом не определяют не ключевые атрибуты *Код заказа*, *Дата заказа* и *Срок выполнения*.